# Make elements in Pandas rows

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas table df:

```
           course
ID
1      physics101
1       astronomy     
2           maths
2         another
```

I'd like to derive a table that has the following result:

```
         physics101    astronomy     maths    another
ID
1              True         True    False        False
2             False        False     True         True
```

What kind of operation is it?

(Elements of df is a defined set of classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this is a best way, try [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html#pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table)

```
In [65]: pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(), rows='ID', \
                        cols='course', aggfunc=lambda x:True, fill_value=False)
Out[65]: 
course another astronomy  maths physics101
ID                                        
1        False      True  False       True
2         True     False   True      False
```

Comment: If you're inside parenthesis you don't need to break the line with \ :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `crosstab()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
data = StringIO("""ID       course
1      physics101
1       astronomy     
2           maths
2         another""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.course) > 0
```

output:

```
course another astronomy  maths physics101
ID                                        
1        False      True  False       True
2         True     False   True      False
```